# How to make modal window HTML 5 and CSS3 work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Okay, so I got this modal window code from this website:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

And someone in the comments said that it would work with IE 9, but it doesn't.

The specific problems are:

1) When you open the webpage, the modal is supposed to be closed, however, it is open.  Also, the gradient is not working either.

2) The close button is visible but is not closing the modal window.

Does anyone know how to make it work with IE 9?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="title"><a href="#openModal">Portal</a></div>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com (not the website I'm trying to go to, but it doesn't matter)" height="600px" width="900px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#title{
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
 background-position: center center;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 145px 15px 15px 15px;
 font-size: 50px;
 background-image: url('blank.jpg');
 height: 70px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 750px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-family: "Copperplate Gothic Light";
}

.modalDialog {
 position:fixed;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top:-5;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target{
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events:auto;
}

.modalDialog div{
 width: 900px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close{
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover{
 background: #CF142B;
}
```

Also, I've seen another solution that doesn't work for me:

```
.modalDialog{
 display:none;
}

.modalDialog{
 display:block;
}
```

But that just made the modal window not show up at all when clicking on the link.

Also, I looked into the console as suggested below, and I found this code that I didn't put in there:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<html lang="en">
<head><style>

</style></head>


<body onload="pageOnLoad()">
<div id="eViewPage">
 <div id="entViewAreaHolder2ID">
  <div id="entViewAreaHolder1ID">
   <div id="aeE0_ID" style="width: 560px; height: 54px;" name="aeE0">
    <div style='width: 100%; height: 54px; background-image: url("PHOTO?AE_ClientID=%7BC58BEBFC%2D212B%2D4EDC%2D87FA%2D95A975C869BA%7D&AE_AppImage=3"); background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 0px; background-position-y: 0px;'></div>
   </div>
   <form name="MainForm" action="LOGIN" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <table width="280" id="aeE1_ID" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr id="aeE1R0_ID" name="aeE1R0">
       <td width="180" align="right" vAlign="middle" style="padding-right: 6px; background-color: aliceblue;">
        <label accessKey="B" for="AE_BadgeID_ID"><u style="accelerator: true;">B</u>adge/ID</label>
       </td>
       <td width="100" align="left" vAlign="middle" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
        <input name="AE_BadgeID" tabIndex="1" id="AE_BadgeID_ID" type="text" alt="Enter your account name here." /> </input><//input>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="aeE1R1_ID" name="aeE1R1">
       <td width="180" align="right" vAlign="middle" style="padding-right: 6px; background-color: aliceblue;">
        <label accessKey="P" for="AE_PIN_ID"><u style="accelerator: true;">P</u>IN</label>
       </td>
       <td width="100" align="left" vAlign="middle" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
        <input name="AE_PIN" tabIndex="2" id="AE_PIN_ID" type="password" alt="Enter your password here." autocomplete="off" /> </input><//input>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="aeE1R2_ID" name="aeE1R2">
       <td width="180" align="right" vAlign="middle" style="padding-right: 6px; background-color: aliceblue;"></td>
       <td width="100" align="left" vAlign="middle" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> </input><//input>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="aeE1R3_ID" name="aeE1R3">
       <td width="180" align="right" vAlign="middle" style="padding-right: 6px; background-color: aliceblue;"></td>
       <td width="100" align="left" vAlign="middle" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
        <input name="AE_HeaderID" type="hidden" value="0" /> </input><//input>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if anyone needs more code to figure it out.

Comment: Does the ie9 console have any errors or information?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of.  There was no dialog box popping up indicating that there was an error.

Comment: P.S.  I've tried chrome, firefox, and safari, and all of those browsers worked.

Comment: Try specifically opening the dev console and looking. If there's a error due to ie9 not parsing something right, it won't pop up a dialog, it just won't work

Comment: I opened the console and I didn't see any errors.

Comment: Although I did find that there was a bunch of code that I didn't code in the console that I didn't add.  I'll add it to the problem up above.

Comment: Try different doctypes?

Comment: Different doctypes did not work.

Comment: I tried 5, 4.01 Strict, Transitional, and Frameset.  Also XHTML 1.0 Strict, Transitional, Frameset, and 1.1.